# TVML listItemLockup click event

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'm using the '[Compilation.xml](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/CompilationTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH36-SW2)' template from the [TVMLCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)

I'd like to add a button click event to a '[listItemLockup](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/LockupElements.html)'

```
<listItemLockup>
  <ordinal minLength="2" class="ordinalLayout">0</ordinal>
  <title>Intro</title>
  <subtitle>00</subtitle>
  <decorationLabel>(3:42)</decorationLabel>
</listItemLockup>
```

I've tried adding:

```
App.onLaunch = function(options) {
    var templateURL = 'http://localhost:8000/hello.tvml';
    var doc = getDocument(templateURL);
    //doc.addEventListener("select", function() { alert("CLICK!") }, false);
    var listItemLockupElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("listItemLockup");
    listItemLockupElement.addEventListener("select", function() { alert("CLICK!") }, false);
}
```

[addEventListener](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSEventListenerObject_Ref/#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/EventListenerObject/addEventListener)

```
void addEventListener (in String type, in Object listener, in optional Object extraInfo)
```

Is "select" the correct type?

I've been using the following tutorials

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-tvos-apps-for-apple-tv-with-swift/

http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-tvos-apps-for-apple-tv-part-2/

---

**Update**

I'm getting an error

```
ITML <Error>: doc.getElementsByTagName is not a function. (In 'doc.getElementsByTagName("listItemLockup")', 'doc.getElementsByTagName' is undefined) - http://localhost:8000/main.js - line:27:58
```

I tried adding this to the 'onLaunch'

```
var listItemLockupElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("listItemLockup");
for (var i = 0; i < listItemLockupElements.length; i++) {   
    //var ele = listItemLockupElements[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    listItemLockupElements[i].addEventListener("select", function() { alert("CLICK!") }, false);
}
```

I'll see about the error first

---

Cross Post: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17859

Comment: I made an edit to respond to your "Update", please check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More common example I have seen by Apple is to define a single overall listener like:

```
doc.addEventListener("select", Presenter.load.bind(Presenter));
```

In your xml, assign unique ids to elements, or give them ways to identify them.
For example, the beginning would be something like:

```
load: function(event) {
        var self = this,
            ele = event.target,
            attr_id = ele.getAttribute("id"),
            audioURL = ele.getAttribute("audioURL"),
            videoURL = ele.getAttribute("videoURL")
```

And then you can do whatever you want with your item.

```
if(audioURL && (event.type === "select" || event.type === "play")) {
//
}
```

My advice would be to study the Presenter.js file more carefully for this pattern.

Edit:
Answering your "Update" related to doc.getElementsByTagName is not a function. "doc" does not actually exist, but the general pattern is to get it with

```
var doc = getActiveDocument();
```

I assumed you would know the above.
Does that fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
var listItemLockupElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("listItemLockup”);
```

In this case, the listItemLockupElement is a NodeList, not an element. You can either iterate through the list and add an event listener to each listItemLockup, or you could add the event listener to the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

When addressing items in a NodeList, you use the item(i) method rather than the standard array access notation:

```
 listItemLockupElements.item(i).addEventListener("select", function() { })
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item

Answer (score 0):

Adding event listeners is straightforward if you're using [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) framework.

```
ATV.Page.create({
    name: 'mypage',
    template: your_template_function,
    data: your_data,
    events: {
        select: 'onSelect',
    },
    // method invoked in the scope of the current object and
    // 'this' will be bound to the object at runtime
    // so you can easily access methods and properties and even modify them at runtime
    onSelect: function(e) {
        let element = e.target;
        let elementType = element.nodeName.toLowerCase();

        if (elementType === 'listitemlockup') {
            this.doSomething();
        }
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        // some awesome action
    }
});

ATV.Navigation.navigate('mypage');
```

*Disclaimer: I am the creator and maintainer of [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) and as of writing this answer, it is the **only** JavaScript framework available for Apple TV development using TVML and TVJS. Hence I could provide references only from this framework. The answer should not be mistaken as a biased opinion.*